# Bootstrap 4 Float-Right not working when line breaks

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is the code:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="w-100 row">
        <div class="d-none d-md-block col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10 row">
            <div class="col-md-3  border">
                <span class="float-md-right">Float right
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 border">
                Align to left
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3  border">
                <span class="float-right">Float right
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 border">
                Align to left
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3  border">
                <span class="float-right h3">Not floating rightside:
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 border">
                Align to left
            </div>
        <div class="d-none d-md-block col-md-1"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Please see this example here: https://jsfiddle.net/4p81h0mo/

Please view it on a large screen.

In the 2nd row there is a cell with text that wraps to a new line, but the space after first line is reserved so it doesn't float to right.

I have also tried d-flex + ml-auto, which only works when there is no line break too.

Comment: `text-align:right;`? something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/68ywe2f5/

Comment: it's floating but the width of the element is bigger than the container